# disk scheduling algorithms in the C language

Tags: c, algorithm, scheduling, disk

I am trying to learn implementation of Disk Scheduling Algorithms (SCAN and C-SCAN) in the C language, can somebody please refer to good sources of implementations of these in the C Language or advise me on programming them on C?

Further Into:-
*Objective is to write a program to optimize disk access to read a non contiguous set of pages on disk to memory, for this, I am performing disk scheduling.

*I would want to instruct the disk on read sequence of the pages

Comment: Is this in C because you're writing a driver? Or are you using some pseudo-computer framework like `nachos`?

Comment: I need a program to optimize disk access to read a non contiguous set of pages on disk to memory, for this, I am performing disk scheduling.

Comment: As in you wish to physically instruct the disk how to read the pages or you would like to know how the disk scans and feed the reads to it in the proper order?

Comment: I would like to physically instruct the disk on reading the pages.

Comment: mm that's sounds interesting. does the OS provide you some API to do that?

Comment: in Windows, I use the CreateFile function with the flag for unbuffered I/O and Write-through switched on. Don't know how far it would take me with disk scheduling.

Comment: SCAN and C-SCAN are very simple algorithms - I'd bet it would be quicker to just code them up than try to integrate something someone else gives or points you to.

Comment: I can tell you this much, the Win32 API is not going to allow you to schedule the reads and writes to *sectors* on a disk...you have a file system you've got to go through first!

Comment: It's fascinating how many people there are on SO to whom everything sounds like homework.

Comment: If anybody is wasting time thinking the question "sounds" like homework.. get your ossicles fixed up...Real thanks to @sixlettervariables for guiding out...Appreciate your help

Comment: Found this out:- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx (See under "Physical Disks and Volumes"), the DeviceIoControl function :http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363216%28v=vs.85%29.aspx to write to the disk directly

Comment: @swanar: one difficulty you'll have is you don't necessarily know how the disk schedules reads/writes. So you may end up making performance worse trying to emulate SCAN/C-SCAN. One approach may be to order the pages you read from disk. i.e. if you need pages 3, 7, 99, 14, and 8 (in a file with some fixed page size), you could just order those pages and read them using increasing address.

Comment: @sixlettervariables To the best I can recept, to what you mean, say I have a file of size PAGE_SIZE*N (where N be any number) and I have to read pages 3,99,40,51 then I should sort them to 3,40,51,99 so that they can be read one after another while the disk rotates (therefore reducing latency) and perform 4 different read commands (in the sorted order) and the OS's disk schedular does the rest...Am I right, please correct me if I am wrong. Thank you!

Comment: Infact this was what I had orginally thought of doing, but I couldnt get to verify results..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic for scheduling disk requests in an efficient fashion should be considered in the domain of the disk itself! Optimizing the order you read data from disk sectors is not likely to be portable or efficient.

However, if you have a file of `npages * PAGE_SIZE`, you could attempt to improve your applications performance when servicing your own internal reads from disk. Given:

```
#define PAGE_SIZE ...
#define MAX_PAGE_READ ...

struct read_req {
    unsigned int page;
    /* any other book-keeping required */
};
```

You could internally sort the requests by `page` (and optionally coalesce neighbor pages):

```
/* qsort-comparer for two read_req structs */
int cmp_req(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    unsigned int pageA = ((struct read_req*)a)->page,
                 pageB = ((struct read_req*)b)->page;
    return pageA == pageB ? 0 : pageA > pageB ? 1 : -1;
}

int service_reads(struct read_req *reqs, size_t nreqs)
{
    size_t ii = 0;

    /* sort read requests in ascending order */
    qsort(reqs, nreqs, sizeof(reqs[0]), cmp_req);

    while (ii < nreqs)
    {
        unsigned int start = reqs[ii].page;
        size_t size = 1;

        while (++ii < nreqs)
        {
            if (reqs[ii].page != (start + size)) break;

            /* expand our read to include the next page,
             * and break if we've read too much
             */
            if (++size == MAX_PAGE_READ) break;
        }

        your_read_logic(start, size);
    }
}
```